# Definite Integrals on Mathematica Online

Tags: mathematica-online

One can `Insert` `Special Characters` on Mathematica Online, including an indefinite integral symbol. Is there a way to use that symbol and compute a definite integral? I'm trying to lower the threshold for use for my colleagues and students.

Comment: Consider also asking on https://community.wolfram.com.  My impression is that few site members here use Mathematica Online regularly. However, some have played with it and might know the answer. -- In regular Mathematica, you put upper and lower limits on the integral sign (somewhat like super & sub scripts). There is probably some way to do that in the Online version, but I don't know it off hand. Maybe you can find it.

Comment: A quick web search indicates that a number of users (on this site, Reddit, Wolfram Community) have asked similar questions regarding sub/super scripts. The community site answer from a WRI developer is 8 years old, and indicates you can't do this in a browser. Another post indicates that the use of the various ctrl keys clashes with things such as browser tab controls. The most recent posts date to 2020-21, so it doesn't appear the situation has changed. These limitations also likely apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The standard mathematical method (and much more swift compared to the integral symbol with limits) to compute definite integrals in Mathematica is

$$\text{Subtract}\text{@@}\left(\int f(x) \, dx \text{/.}\, \{\{x\to b\},\{x\to a\}\}   \right)$$

Comment: No, Don't do that. If you want a definite integral, use a definite integral. Guessing that the antiderivative crosses no path singularities, in the absence of any information to indicate that, is just really bad usage.

Comment: After use of definite integrals always do it for comparison. If no complex path of integration is given, its anyway free to decide what to do. And then there is stackexchange where perhaps are two or three people knowing how to do standard integrals, special functions and integral transforms. In order to vary a classical statement: Any AI blockhead can differerentiate, but its an ingenious, creative art to integrate. Of  course, with repsect to the original question to lower treshholds for colleagues and students I dont expect any positive results.

Comment: One is always welcome to use Newton-Leibniz to compare to the result of a definite integral. In and of itself that's a reasonable thing to do. Using it blindly, without any investigation of the antiderivative for path singularities, is a bad idea. So by extension it is a bad idea to use this as a way of getting a definite integral in Mathematica Online. Which was an important aspect of the original question.